# Comprobar si la posición x de un arraylist ya tiene un dato

Tags: java, arraylist, if

Pretendo comprobar si la posición de un arraylist de tipo String esta ocupada, es decir tengo un jframe con 4 botones de nombre 1,2,3,4 respectivamente lo que quiero hacer es que cuando presione el boton que sea, compruebe si en la posición del boton de mi arraylist ya existe un nombre, si no me deje ingresar uno.

```
//  
if(usuario[pos] != 0){  
    loquesea;  
}else{   
    loquesea;   
}  
//
```

este fragmento de código es exactamente lo que quiero hacer, pero con un arraylist.

Gracias De Antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un ArrayList no funciona igual que un array, no se respetan las posiciones, salvo que introduzcas elementos vacíos.
Lo que puedes hacer es algo similar a esto:

Inicializas el ArrayList con Strings vacíos

```
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
lista.add("");
lista.add("");
lista.add("");
lista.add("");
```

Añades la validación:

```
if ("".equals(lista.get(pos))){
    //la posición pos no se ha rellenado
}else{
    //la posición pos ya tiene valor
}
```

Comment: Gracias por Contestar Pablo, me ha sido de mucha ayuda, efectivamente, la manera que propusiste funciona como lo esperaba, muchísimas gracias, ya solo agrege dentro del `if` `lista.add(pos,nombre);` y funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, usa el metodo [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) de List

```
if(arrayList.get(pos) != 0){
    //loquesea;
}else{
    //loquesea;
}
```

Comment: **me sale bad operand type for binary operator**  **firt tyoe string**  **Second type int**  segun tengo entendido el metodo get sirve para obtener el dato que esta en la posisicon que le pidamos, por lo que segun entiendo el error radica en que ahi directamente comparo si lo que esta en la posicion 0 del arraylist(que es un String) es diferente a 0. no se igual y estoy diciendo tonterias. @Lithorell

Comment: Si es un String tendras que comparar con equals.

Comment: He probado con el equals, y resulta que funciona , pero solo la primera vez, es decir al iniciar al programa por primera vez, dice que no tiene nada como es de esperarse y me deja introducir el dato, pero a la hora de volver a dar click no manda el error de que esta ocupado, pero gracias por responder, me ampliaron el panorama de lo que tenia que hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Siendo un ArrayList de strings, puedes preguntar si la longitud del elemento en la posición es mayor de 0.

```
if(miArrayList.get(pos).length() > 0){
    //loquesea;
}else{
    //loquesea;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar, lo hep robado y no marca ningun error de compilacion pero al correrlo y ejecutarlo se crashea y marca que el error esta en la linea del if :( pero gracias de nuevo por responder.

Comment: Puede ser porque el ArrayList esté vacío y no tenga elementos en ese momento, en ese caso intentar acceder a una posición dentro del ArrayList producirá error, o porque la posición esté fuera de rango.

Answer (score -2):

Comprueba que no es NULL dicha posición del `array`

```
if(arrayList[pos] != NULL){
    //loquesea;
}else{
    //loquesea;
}
```

Comment: Un arrayList es distinto a un array por lo que `arrayList[pos]` dara un error de compilación.